# Group policy WMI Logon Server

Tags: windows-server-2012, group-policy, wmi

I'm trying to setup a GP to do tasks if in a certain location, I believe the best way in doing this is a WMI filter. Could someone help me out? I've never used this part of GP before.

Was looking online and it seem that Win32_NetworkLoginProfile is the right method to detect what logon server they're using (which would indicate the location)?

Anyone have past experience in this

Comment: Certain locations, like offices, countries, etc.? If so you want to think about OU structure and not WMI Filters.. WMI Filters are used for versions of Windows so you can have a GPO that only applies to Windows XP by using WMI Filters to ignore windows vista, 7, etc.

Comment: It's being applied to laptops which will be switching between office locations. So will need to be done using logon server

Comment: It's not easy to target using logon server as this is not going to definitely change just because the laptop is in another office (it can sometimes cache the logon server and use this one whatever location).. You can however target IP ranges so if the laptop is taken to another office and pick up a new IP in their DHCP range it will apply different polices could this help?